# What would cause an app to (globally) have ANR Dialogs instead of throwing exceptions?

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception, android-anr-dialog

I recently took over an Android project where I need to make alterations to their networking classes. I have updated them to the new endopints / variables, but am having some weird problems.

The largest one is, every time something breaks in the app (Any type of exception, IE, NullPointer), instead of force closing and popping up the standard dialog box of "X has stopped working", it pops up with the Anddroid Not Responding (ANR) popup; "X isn't responding".

It is possible that there is some global functionality in the app (IE, prefs in the manifest or whatnot) that can cause this to happen? Or is it more likely that something in the app is hanging (IE a loading animation) which is causing this? Is there even such a thing as a global ANR throw condition in the Android framework?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#anr

Comment: It's hard to say without some example code but, basically, you are doing long running operations on the UI thread

Comment: @codeMagic gotcha, So the short answer is no, there isn't such a thing as a global ANR setting and the best idea to hunt down the issue is to look for non-threaded operations. Is that about right?

Comment: the most common of anrs are from doing either file or network ops on the ui/main thread.  so search for all file & net usage and check it's threadedness